# PHP file download strange error

Tags: php, file, download, rtf

I'm having an error when downloading file via PHP.

the code:

```
if(file_exists($myFile)) {
  $mm_type="application/octet-stream";

  header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate");
  header("Pragma: hack"); // WTF? oh well, it works...
  header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
  header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($myFile)) );
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");

  $fp = fopen($myFile, 'rb');
  $buffer = fread($fp, filesize($myFile));
  fclose ($fp);

  print $buffer;
}
```

The above code works on doc files, pdf files, zip files, jpg/png files,

but fails when I try to download .rtf or .txt files.

Tested on all major browsers (Chrome, FF, IE, Safari).

Also tried using as mime-type : `application/force-download` without luck.

The error:

I'm getting an error in Chrome:

`This webpage is not available`

in Firefox:

`The page isn't redirecting properly`

`Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.`

Comment: What means "not working" to you?

Comment: sidenote, also use `filename="'.basename($filename).'"`

Comment: made an edit, described the error I'm getting

Comment: You error is not in your download script. The loop redirect is caused by something else. Check the code where you have redirects.

Comment: @machineaddict : but it works for the other files, as I described. The error is shown exclusively if I try to download .rtf or .txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solved the problem:

```
if (file_exists($myFile)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename));
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($myFile));
        readfile($myFile);
        exit;
    }
```

source: [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add content type for .rtf and .txt files

first check the file extension and then in

if else condition you set the content type for .rtf and .txt files

Cheers :)

I think this should help you here you find all content types

http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/